# Script to move files automatically - without root

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, file-system, file-transfer, file-management, files

I would like that when lauching an app / clicking on a desktop button of the phone, this happens automatically on my Android 5 **non-rooted** phone:

```
mv /extSD/DCIM/*.* /extSD/phone/
mv /internal/DCIM/Retrica/*.* /extSD/phone/
mv /extSD/Sounds/*.* /extSD/phone/
```

As these are simple operations (non security-sensitive), is there a solution for a non-rooted phone?

Comment: The button option would be doable with Terminal Emulator's widget, which can run a command.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman does it work without root? If so, [should I use this](https://lh5.ggpht.com/HdUhEvBlitTTqIz0UC-LbKeLfmQuKwmQoG7YOt_okbjfCt0TcQuhTjHAEZtqnkg6FyRt=h900) with `command`, Arguments : `mv /extSD/DCIM/*.* /extSD/phone/ ; 
mv /internal/DCIM/Retrica/*.* /extSD/phone/ ; mv /extSD/Sounds/*.* /extSD/phone/` with semicolon `;`to separe the different lines ?

Comment: It should be the correct command, yes. And it doesn't require root.